# Calling java project from Mathematica

Tags: java, wolfram-mathematica, jlink

Could you please give me a hint how can I invoke a java project (written in eclipse) from Mathematica? I want to give values generated by my Mathematica program as input to a java project, and use the (outputs) results obtained from solving the problem by java, as input to my Mathematica code. I know there is a J/Link package for calling java from mathematica. But, i don't know how I can have this interaction between them.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your project is on the class path, you can pull in Java pretty easily([see docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica.html))

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

awesomeClass = LoadJavaClass["my.java.class.OfAwesomeness"];

awesomeClass`crazyStaticMethod[];

awesomeInstance = JavaNew[awesomeClass,"Awesome Arg 1"];
awesomeInstance@superCoolMethod[1,2,3];
```

Comment: I made a jar file from my project which is run with no problem from command prompt. However, when I run it in Mathematica with Run[.] command, it gives me the following error:
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: data\test_7 (The system cannot find the path specified)"
for an input file, which is called from within my java program like this:
static Graph graph = new VariableGraph("C:\\Mas\\data\\test_7");

How should I define the paths to be able to get rid of this error and run my jar file in Mathematica?

Comment: You could try loading your VariableGraph class in Mathematica and trying to initialize it with your data file.