# Java and Mathematica interaction

Tags: java, wolfram-mathematica

How can I use Java within Mathematica?

I have two files,`GRASP.nb` and `GRASP.java`, in the same folder (BTW: GRASP=greedy randomized adaptive search procedure). The `GRASP.java` file contains a method `public static int[] TSP(int[][] g, int numberOfIterations, int k)`. I'd like to call this method within Mathematica.

I read in the Mathematica documentation, and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176697/calling-java-project-from-mathematica), that I should write

```
Needs["JLink`"]; 
InstallJava[]; 
obj=JavaNew[NotebookDirectory[]~~"GRASP.java"]
```

or

```
Needs["JLink`"]; 
InstallJava[]; 
obj=LoadJavaClass[NotebookDirectory[]~~"GRASP.java"]
```

or something like it, but anything I try, returns an error. I have WinXP, Mathematica 7, Eclipse 3.6.

Any working example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget to compile the Java class first -- you cannot load `GRASP.java` directly.

After compilation, try the following:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[]];
LoadJavaClass["GRASP"];
GRASP`TSP[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, 7, 8]
```

Since the `TSP` method is a static method, you must load the Java class itself before you can access it.  Note that the class becomes a Mathematica context named `GRASP` and that the static method is accessed as a symbol in that context (`` GRASP`TSP ``, as shown above).

If the method you wanted to access were a regular method (not static), then the calling sequence would look like this instead:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[]];
obj = JavaNew["GRASP"];
obj@someMethod[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, 7, 8]
```

All of this assumes that your Java class is contained in the default package -- an unusual circumstance.  If the class were contained in a named package, then the syntax would be like this:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[]];
LoadJavaClass["com.stackoverflow.GRASP"];
com`stackoverflow`GRASP`TSP[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, 7, 8]
```

or

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[]];
obj = JavaNew["com.stackoverflow.GRASP"];
obj@someMethod[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, 7, 8]
```

If the class *is* in a named package (`com.stackoverflow` in my examples), then make sure that the class has the path `com/stackoverflow/GRASP.class` relative to the notebook.  This is a requirement of Java, not Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

The StackOverflow post you link to shows the name of the Java class (GRASP) not the name of the source file, being passed as the argument, so definitely lose the `.java`. Also, you'll need to compile the source file to produce a `GRASP.class` file, as that's the format that can actually be loaded. That might be as simple as just

```
javac GRASP.java
```

but it might be harder, depending on what's in that file. Likewise, the name of the class might not be just `GRASP` -- if there's a `package com.foo.something` statement in the file, then the argument is going to be `com.foo.something.GRASP`.